# Iterate Chinese string in Lua / Torch

Tags: lua

I have a lua string in Chinese, such as

```
str = '这是一个中文字符串' -- in English: 'this is a Chinese string'
```

Now I would like to iterate the string above, to get the following result:

```
str[1] = '这'
str[2] = '是'
str[3] = '一'
str[4] = '个'
str[5] = '中'
str[6] = '文'
str[7] = '字'
str[8] = '符' 
str[9] = '串'
```

and also output `9` for the length of the string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work if you are using `utf8` module from Lua 5.3 or [luautf8](https://github.com/starwing/luautf8), which works with LuaJIT:

```
local str = '这是一个中文字符串'
local tbl = {}
for p, c in utf8.codes(str) do
  table.insert(tbl, utf8.char(c))
end
print(#tbl) -- prints 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used non-english characters in lua before and my emulator just puts them in as '?' but something along the lines of this might work:

```
convert = function ( str )
    local temp = {}
    for c in str:gmatch('.') do
        table.insert(temp, c)
    end
    return temp
end
```

This is a simple function that utilizes string.gmatch() to separate the string into individual characters and save them into a table. It would be used like this:

```
t = convert('abcd')
```

Which would make 't' a table containing a, b, c and d.

```
t[1] = a
t[2] = b
...
```

I am not sure if this will work for the Chinese characters but it is worth a shot.

Comment: The functions in the standard string library in Lua do not handle multichar text.